# convert list of tuples to tuples of list(query set object into list)?

Tags: django, list, django-queryset

I am getting queryset object which I want to convert it into only list.

```
[<yyyy : val1 val2 val3 val4 xxxx@xxx.com True True>, <yyyy : 2   None  False True>]
```

I tried by

```
res.values_list()
```

But I am getting

```
[(val1,val2,val3,val4),(val11,val22,val33,val44)]
```

Comment: Why do you need this conversion? Tuple is a (immutable) list afterall. Do you want to modify it?

Comment: I want to send query set object into csv file.but in csv file method only list objects can be given.

Comment: If ou are talking about `csv.writer.writerow/s()` functions, you will have no problem using tuples (because they are lists also). You don't need this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

```
tuple(list(obj) for obj in res.values_list())
```